# Attach content to div depending of data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Trying to detach an html element with specific data attribute when clicking on link with the same attribute and then attach it to another div. Got code that detects which element was clicked but can't figure out working solution.

Will be glad to any help. Thank you in advance.

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".modal-trigger").click(function() {
                var modalContent = $(this);
                var $modalContent = $('.modal-inner').detach();
                $('.modal').append($modalContent).fadeIn();
            });

            $('.modal-trigger').on('click', function () {
                var modalContent = $(this);
                console.log(modalContent.data('content'));
                $('')
            });
 
        });
```

```css
.modal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999;
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="div">
        <p class="modal-inner" data-content="modal-1">Content 1</p>
        <p class="modal-inner" data-content="modal-2">Content 2</p>
        <p class="modal-inner" data-content="modal-3">Content 3</p>
    </div>

    <a class="modal-trigger" data-content="modal-1" href="#">Trigger 1</a>
    <a class="modal-trigger" data-content="modal-2" href="#">Trigger 2</a>
    <a class="modal-trigger" data-content="modal-3" href="#">Trigger 3</a>

    <div class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "another div" to which div do you want to add the content when you click trigger 1?

Comment: Sorry if did'nt explained well. When click on modal-trigger with data-content="modal-1" want to detach <p> with the same data attribute and attach it to the div .modal

Comment: Alright, so you want to append the data? Or should there only be Content 1 or Content 2 or Content 3 in the modal div?

Comment: Ah okay. And the <p> should stay there as well? So in the div

Comment: want to append the whole <p> element to the div with class "modal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so let's see if I understood your problem.

See the code here:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.modal-trigger').on('click', function () {
$(".modal-inner").show();
            var modalContent = $(this);
            var modalSelector = modalContent.data('content');
            var content = $('.modal-inner[data-content="' + modalSelector +'"]');
            var contentToAdd = content.clone();
            $(".modal-inner").hide();
            $('.modal').append(contentToAdd).fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Here in action: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/41855/

It is not quite clear if you want to replace the content or just add the content to the existing. But maybe it is now clear for you how to get the div and attach it to another div. This should help you get to your solution.

Comment: You're right, when some <p> is already attached and click to another trigger, need to hide the old content and then attach the content of the clicked <p>. Tried to hide all <p>'s when click on some trigger but don't seem to work that way.

Comment: But when do you want to show the <p> elements again? :)

Comment: Almost. Thank you for your efforts but with replacing detach method and storing <p>'s HTML as variable you can attach same <p> many times and that's not what i wanted.

I want to have only one <p> element with certain data attribute and to detach and attach it back when I need it.

Comment: Alright, but now you have a baseline for your problem :)

Comment: How do you want to detach it back? When another p is attached?

Comment: Thanks. Will continue trying...

Yes, detaching element when another p is attached.

Comment: simply changed var contentToAdd = content.clone(); to var contentToAdd = content.detach(); and everything worked.

Thank you!

Comment: Awesome :) So glad that you found the right solutions with a bit of help :)